# Subset function does not evaluate arguments

Tags: r, function, subset, argument-passing

Using the below data frame called 'data', I'm able to directly assign values to two variables, 'state' and 'measure', and identify the school with the lowest score within the subset:

Create dataframe 'data':

```
school<-c("NYU", "BYU", "USC", "FIT", "Oswego","UCLA","USF","Columbia")
state<-c("NY","UT","CA","NY","NY","CA", "CA","NY")
measure<-c("MSAT","MSAT","GPA","MSAT","MSAT","GPA","GPA","GPA")
score<-c(590, 490, 2.9, 759, 550, 1.2, 3.1, 3.2)
data<-data.frame(school,state, measure,score)
```

Subset on a 'state' and 'measure':

```
answer<-subset(data,subset=(state=="NY" & measure=="MSAT"))
order.answer<-order(answer$score,answer$school) #answer$school is tie-breaker
answer1<-as.matrix(answer[order.answer,])
answer1[1,1]
```

This is the correct answer:

```
[1] "Oswego"
```

My problem is that when I create a function to accomplish the same thing, I get an incorrect result:

```
lowest <- function(state, measure){
    answer<-subset(data,subset=(state==state & measure==measure))
    order.answer<-order(answer$score,answer$school)
    answer1<-as.matrix(answer[order.answer,])
    answer1[1,1]
  }

lowest("NY","MSAT")
```

Incorrect answer:

```
[1] "UCLA"
```

The problem seems to be that the variables 'state' and 'measure' don't take on the values of the arguments "NY" and "MSAT" in the subset line of the function. I've experimented with '=' instead of '==' and also tried subset(data,subset=(state=="state" & measure=="measure")), but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be something going awry in your function call related to the fact that your function arguments are the same as your data columns because this works

```
lowest <- function(State, Measure){
  answer<-subset(data,subset=(state==State & measure==Measure))
  order.answer<-order(answer$score,answer$school)
  answer1<-as.matrix(answer[order.answer,])
  answer1[1,1]
}
##
> lowest("NY","MSAT")
[1] "Oswego"
```

UPDATE: After mulling this over a bit more, I think I can offer a little more detail about what is going on internally. Notice that your first (manual) subset worked correctly above:

```
> subset(data,subset=(state=="NY" & measure=="MSAT"))
  school state measure score
1    NYU    NY    MSAT   590
4    FIT    NY    MSAT   759
5 Oswego    NY    MSAT   550
```

However, notice that if we create two objects in the global environment, `state <- "NY"` and `measure <- "MSAT"`, this does not work

```
state <- "NY"
measure <- "MSAT" 
> subset(data,state==state & measure==measure)
    school state measure score
1      NYU    NY    MSAT 590.0
2      BYU    UT    MSAT 490.0
3      USC    CA     GPA   2.9
4      FIT    NY    MSAT 759.0
5   Oswego    NY    MSAT 550.0
6     UCLA    CA     GPA   1.2
7      USF    CA     GPA   3.1
8 Columbia    NY     GPA   3.2
```

The reason (I believe) has to do with the R's scope resolution mechanism and how it operates within functions. When a function is called in R, this function call creates a (temporary?) environment where the objects in that function reside in the local frame, i.e. they are prioritized in the sense that if you have a variable `x` in the global environment, and a function defined as `foo <- function(x){do something interesting to x}`, that `do something interesting` is acting on the object passed into the `foo` via the argument `x`, and **not** the object `x` in the global environment. However, R uses *dynamic scoping*, meaning that if the object referred to in the local frame is not found, the interpreter will recursively search through the hierarchy of frames / environments until it finds the object referred to. So if instead of `foo <- function(x){do something interesting to x}` you had `foo(z){do something interesting to x}`, but you **still** had `x` defined in the global environment, rather than result in an error, the function would search through the call stack until it found the object `x` to "do something interesting" to.

In the example directly above, the reason `subset(data,state==state & measure==measure)` did not produce the desired results and `subset(data,state=="NY & measure=="MSAT")` did is because in the `subset(data, ...)` function call, `data` and all of its columns were in the local scope, i.e. the columns `state` and `measure` were prioritized over the objects `state` and `measure` in the global environment. Therefore, the subsetting condition `state==state & measure==measure` evaluated as `TRUE` for each row of `data`, and so the "subset" returned was the entirety of `data`. Now, if we do

```
State <- "NY"
Measure <- "MSAT"
> subset(data, state==State & measure==Measure)
  school state measure score
1    NYU    NY    MSAT   590
4    FIT    NY    MSAT   759
5 Oswego    NY    MSAT   550
```

this works fine, because since `State` and `Measure` are not found in the local frame of the `subset` function call, the interpreter will keep searching through environments until it first encounters these objects (in this case, it finds them in the global environment). This is why when I changed the arguments to `State` and `Measure` (and made the respective changes in the function body) in your function `lowest` it produced the desired results - really you could change them to just about anything, as long as the names do not clash with the column names of `data`, but capitalizing their first letter was a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks @nrussell. You mention that R uses dynamic scoping, but several sources I looked at, including http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-scope.pdf, say that R uses lexical or static scoping. Anyway, this is just semantics. Your explanation of my scoping problem was very helpful.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You're right that the particular situation I was referring to is a case of lexical scoping, for the record though, `R has two types of scoping: lexical scoping, implemented automatically at the language level, and dynamic scoping, used in select functions to save typing during interactive analysis.` - from Hadley's [Advanced R manual](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) (definitely a "must read" for R).